# Dúvida sobre services angularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-services

Uma dica por favor, se eu tenho um serviço `ServiceY` e esse serviço possui um atributo `ServiceY.nome`. Na mesma tela possuo quatro `controller`, sendo: `controller_A`, `controller_B`, `controller_C` e `controller_D` sendo que os quatro `controller` utilizam o mesmo serviço.

Quando eu estou no `controller_A` e faço uma determinada ação, seto um valor dentro de `ServiceY.nome`, no `controller_B` eu faço um *get* do valor presente no `ServiceY.nome` passado anteriormente e obtenho o resultado correto.

Agora, dentro do `controller_C` eu vou setar o `ServiceY.nome` e no `controller_D` vou ler esse atributo, porém não quero alterar os valores do `controller_A` e `controller_B`. Qual seria a melhor forma de fazer isso?

Comment: Criar um "nome" para cada caso não serve? `ServiceY.nomeA` e `ServiceY.nomeC`. Ou então criar outro service. Mas compartilhar o mesmo não é possível.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se eu entendi corretamente, você quer isolar escopos de instâncias de `ServiceY`:

- `controller_A` e `controller_B` compartilham uma instância (vamos chamá-la `ISY1` para fins de referência);
- `controller_C` e `controller_D` compartilham uma outra instância (`ISY2`).

Eu sugeriria então a utilização de um *factory* ao invés de um *service*. A característica que define um *service* é o fato de que este é um *singleton* - uma instância única; *factories* criam uma nova instância para cada objeto consumidor (no seu caso, uma instância por controle).

A seguir um exemplo que implementa uma *factory* com um método, `register()`, onde um parâmetro indica a instância a ser compartilhada:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Clique em <kbd>Executar</kbd> para vê-lo em ação:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .factory('factoryCompartilhada', function () {

        var itens = {}; // coleção de instâncias

        return {
            register: function (codigo) {
                if (!itens[codigo]) // se não existe,
                  itens[codigo] = {dado: codigo}; // cria instância
                  
                return itens[codigo]; // retorna instância
            }
        }
    })

    .controller('ctrlA', function ($scope, factoryCompartilhada) {
        $scope.instanciaFactory = factoryCompartilhada.register('ISY1');
    })
    .controller('ctrlB', function ($scope, factoryCompartilhada) {
        $scope.instanciaFactory = factoryCompartilhada.register('ISY1');
    })
    .controller('ctrlC', function ($scope, factoryCompartilhada) {
        $scope.instanciaFactory = factoryCompartilhada.register('ISY2');
    })
    .controller('ctrlD', function ($scope, factoryCompartilhada) {
        $scope.instanciaFactory = factoryCompartilhada.register('ISY2');
    })
    ;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller='ctrlA'>
      Controller_A: <input ng-model='instanciaFactory.dado' />
  </div>
  <div ng-controller='ctrlB'>
      Controller_B: <input ng-model='instanciaFactory.dado' />
  </div>
  <div ng-controller='ctrlC'>
      Controller_C: <input ng-model='instanciaFactory.dado' />
  </div>
  <div ng-controller='ctrlD'>
      Controller_D: <input ng-model='instanciaFactory.dado' />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfeito, era exatamente essa minha dúvida. muito obrigado.

Comment: @felipesudrj Sempre um prazer ajudar! Sinta-se à vontade para marcar a resposta como 'aceita' - isso facilita a busca por soluções de usuários que tenham a mesma dúvida no futuro. Abraços!